# Does Firebase authentication work in Unity 2020 for Desktop builds?

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine

We're having a time trying to get Firebase authentication up and running in Unity 2020.3.11f1 for OS X and Windows builds, as all of the tutorials seem to be about creating Mobile builds.

So here are a some simple questions:

1. Does anyone have this working on desktop builds?  Any resources to point us to that would help?
2. In [Pat Martin's blog post](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2020/08/firebase-compatibility-with-unity-20201.html) from over a year ago he starts to talk about compatibility but then the topic seems to morph to changes to the Android build settings. It's confusing. What is up with that?
3. Anyone know when the SDK is going to be updated to support 2020?  It's over a year now since that blog post!

Thank you for your advice!

Comment: The question is tagged Firebase and asks about macOS so I will mention that Firebase officially dropped support for macOS a number of years ago, which is why all the docs point to iOS solutions. While there is third party support which generally works, we have encountered some challenges. Not saying it's not possible but be prepared. Also, this question is a discussion type question (and asks for resources/doc) which is not well-suited for SO. SO is for coding specific questions; write some code and when you get stuck, post it and we'll take a look.

Comment: As an update *Firebase 8.9.0 introduces official beta support for macOS*.

Answer (score 0):

linked blog author here

The SDK [does work](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/unity#version_6160_-_october_2_2020) in Unity 2020 (and 2021) as of version 6.16.0. It even works with x86 and x86_64 ChromeOS builds [now](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/unity#version_840_-_october_13_2021) (as of 8.4.0). I apologize for not writing additional blog posts covering the topic (I don't work on Firebase anymore, but I remain a huge fan!).

For desktop support:

The Firebase SDK does work on Desktop, but is still considered beta status. You couldn't test features in the Unity editor otherwise. I don't cover desktop support in that article, but I do mention it in some other contexts.

Based on the table [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cpp/setup?platform=android#libraries-desktop), as of right now (Nov 8, 2021) you can expect the following libraries to function at beta quality:
[Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/cpp/start), [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart), [Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable), [Cloud Storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/cpp/start), [Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/cpp/start), [Remote Config](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/get-started?platform=cpp)

It's not possible to communicate about roadmaps here, but both the [C++](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-cpp-sdk) and [Unity](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-unity-sdk) SDKs are open source. Bugs you file on either issue tracker will be updated as they're addressed (including desktop bugs, note that historically bugs with the Firebase SDK for Unity have been filed [here](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-unity/issues)). PRs may also be accepted if you find issues in the desktop SDKs.

There are example projects in both SDK repos, but I also wrote a tutorial [here](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-add-firebase-to-your-c-desktop-game-4a177703186e) for integrating Unity into a desktop project. As Jay mentions, if you run into issues specifically around desktop builds feel free to ask further questions.

To further address Jay's comment. If you're just interested in macOS support and not C++ or game engine support, there's a separate compatibility matrix here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/learn-more#firebase_library_support_by_platform

Comment: Thanks for the answer - super good info and  the link for the macOS Support! *Firebase 8.9.0 introduces official beta support for macOS*